# Are there any C preprocessor variables?

Tags: c, variables, c-preprocessor

Is there anything like a preprocessor variable in **C**? It could simplify my definitions.

Currently I have something like this:

```
typedef struct mystruct {
  int val1;
  int val2;
  int val3;
  int val4;
} MYSTRUCT;

typedef struct mysuperstruct {
  MYSTRUCT *base;
  int val;
} MYSUPERSTRUCT;


#define MY_OBJECT_BEGIN(name, val1, val2, val3, val4) \
  MYSTRUCT name##Base = { val1, val2, val3, val4 }; \
  MYSUPERSTRUCT * name##Objs = {

#define MY_OBJECT_VALUE(name, val) \
  { &(name##Base), val },

#define MY_OBJECT_END() \
  NULL \
};
```

It is used this way:

```
MY_OBJECT_BEGIN(obj1, 1, 2, 3, 4)
MY_OBJECT_VALUE(obj1, 5)
MY_OBJECT_VALUE(obj1, 6)
MY_OBJECT_VALUE(obj1, 7)
MY_OBJECT_END()
```

Which generates something like this:

```
MYSTRUCT obj1Base = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
MYSUPERSTRUCT * obj1Objs = {
  { &(obj1Base), 5 },
  { &(obj1Base), 6 },
  { &(obj1Base), 7 },
  NULL
}
```

It's obvious that repetitive use of the object name is redundant. I would like to store the name in the MY_OBJECT_BEGIN definition to some preprocessor variable so that I can use it the following way:

```
MY_OBJECT_BEGIN(obj1, 1, 2, 3, 4)
MY_OBJECT_VALUE(5)
MY_OBJECT_VALUE(6)
MY_OBJECT_VALUE(7)
MY_OBJECT_END()
```

Does standard **C** preprocessor provide a way to achieve this?

Comment: I always like to mention [*X macros*](http://www.drdobbs.com/the-new-c-x-macros/184401387) when this sort of thing comes up...

Comment: The best option is: don't do this, fix your program design instead. Because if you find yourself needing to do exotic things with macros, it is a certain indicator of bad design. "X macros" are mostly helpful as a last resort, when everything else has failed, and they are mostly for maintaining old code where you can't fix the design.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are no standard C preprocessor variables.  As [Oli Charlesworth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/129570/oli-charlesworth) suggested, using [X-Macros](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Macro) is probably your best bet if you want to keep it just with standard C.  If there really is a lot of associated data that would touch several files, you'll want to use a code generator like [GNU autogen](http://www.gnu.org/software/autogen/).

Comment: +1 for X-Macros AND autogen, which I hadn't heard of and am now looking into for much more general usage....

Comment: Thank you both, Oli and ldav1s. X-Macros is an interesting technique but not very nice for this purpose when the macros are defined in a kind of library. The autogen also is not what I want. So I'll probably have to stay with my redundant version. But thank you both again, you answered my question.

Answer (score 2):

Create a H file somewhere, that clears all possible defines related to your macros, e.g.:

```
#ifdef OBJECT
#    undef OBJECT
#endif
```

Then make a define for that H file somewhere in your project:

```
#define CLEAR "whatever/path/you/want/clear.h"
```

Make your macros use OBJECT:

```
#define MY_OBJECT_BEGIN(val1, val2, val3, val4) \
  MYSTRUCT OBJECT##Base = { val1, val2, val3, val4 }; \
  MYSUPERSTRUCT * OBJECT##Objs = {

#define MY_OBJECT_VALUE(val) \
  { &(OBJECT##Base), val },

#define MY_OBJECT_END() \
  NULL \
};
```

Use it like this:

```
#include CLEAR
#define OBJECT obj1
MY_OBJECT_BEGIN(1, 2, 3, 4)
MY_OBJECT_VALUE(5)
MY_OBJECT_VALUE(6)
MY_OBJECT_VALUE(7)
MY_OBJECT_END()

#include CLEAR
#define OBJECT obj2
MY_OBJECT_BEGIN(1, 2, 3, 4)
MY_OBJECT_VALUE(5)
MY_OBJECT_VALUE(6)
MY_OBJECT_VALUE(7)
MY_OBJECT_END()
```

Placing the clear code into an own file makes it easier in case you may need multiple defines in the future for your object definitions, as then you only need to add the clear code modifications to one file only.

I know it's not ideal but it's the best thing you can do, as there is no way you can use a macro argument to somehow modify pre-processor code.

Comment: Agree, the solution is not ideal, but this seems workable (didn't test it, the question is outdated). It could be helpful for someone. Thanks for sharing your solution ;-)

Comment: @yman Yeah, I've seen it's old but it's the top hit when you search for preprocessor and variables. So I thought I answer it anyway for people coming from search engines. I once implemented an own C objective language extension entirely with the preprocessor and pushed it to its limits and this was the best I could come up with in the end to solve a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the closest general technique I could come up with off the top of my head for reusing variables across pre-processor definitions:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define INIT_VALS(SIZE) unsigned int value[SIZE]; unsigned int i = 0;
#define DEFINE_VAL(NEW_VAL) value[i++] = NEW_VAL;
#define PRINT_VAL(INDEX) printf("%d\n", value[INDEX]);

int main()
{
    INIT_VALS(3)
    DEFINE_VAL(42)
    DEFINE_VAL(70)
    DEFINE_VAL(80)
    PRINT_VAL(0)
    PRINT_VAL(1)
    PRINT_VAL(2)

    // Output:
    // 42
    // 70
    // 80

    return 0;
}
```

I'm not promoting this, though; be sure to carefully consider if there isn't a preferable solution. :)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion David, but this way the array is not filled by preprocessor, it requires some CPU time, and hence it is not a preferable solution for me.

Comment: Someone correct me if I'm wrong, but I think it'd be a reasonable expectation that with typical compiler optimizations C code such as the contents of INIT_VALS() and DEFINE_VAL() are going to result in about the same amount of CPU time as the method shown in your examples--i.e., with either method (not the exact code), there has to be instructions to initialize values and presumably the compiler could get to about the same point in either case.